# Erro ao usar socket.recv()

Tags: python, socket

Eu estou aprendendo sobre servidores em python e estou usando a biblioteca socket. Mas quando uso o comando `socket.recv(1024)` para o servidor ler o que o cliente mandou, o IDLE dá o seguinte erro:

> 'socket' object has no attribute 'recv'.

O que poderia ser?

O código:

```
import socket

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "localhost"
porta = 5000

confirma = cliente.connect((host, porta))

if (confirma) == -1:
    print("ACESSO NEGADO")

else:
    print("ACESSO PERMITIDO")
    while True:
        pergunta = cliente.recv(1024)
        print(pergunta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu codigo do socket **cliente**, funcionou normalmente, pode ser problemas no socket **server**

**Server socket:**

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(( "localhost", 5000 ))
s.listen(20)

try:
   conn, addr = s.accept()

   conectado = "Conectado ao server!".encode()

   conn.sendall(conectado)

   client = str(addr)
   print("Conectado: {}".format(client) )

   msg = str(conn.recv(4096))
   print("Mensagem: {}".format(msg) )
except:
   conn.close()
   s.close()
```

Fiz o teste com o seu client socket, funcionou perfeitamente!

.

Não sei se conseguir te ajudar, mas espero que sim!